# How to use local images in angular while using routes?

Tags: angular, routes

I'm very new to angular and I'm recently learning routes but I have a problem.
In my app I use the following routes.
My problem is when I try to link to an image in assets folder I get an error that there is no route for the link and the image is not shown.
How can I fix that?

Here is the routes I defined:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/recipes', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'recipes', component: RecipesComponent},
  { path: 'shopping-list', component: ShoppingListComponent},
];
```

Image path : src\assets\images\tastySchnitzel.jpg

Error : Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/images/tastySchnitzel.jpg

Comment: Can you share the exact error and src url of the image that you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the path as below. This solved the same issue for me :

`<img src="/assets/images/tastySchnitzel.jpg" />`

Just add / before assets.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what he wanted to do. But I leave two examples here, I hope that there will be a solution for you;

**If you want show image;**

```
<img src="assets/images/tastySchnitzel.jpg" />
```

**If you want open image in a new tab;**

```
<a href="assets/images/tastySchnitzel.jpg">Link to Image</a>
```

Comment: I want to show the image but my problem is that it's not shown and when I try to open it in a new tab it gives me the error I mentioned